# How can I integrate Vue 3, using Vite, with an ASP.NET MVC 4 project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, vuejs3, vite

I have an existing MVC 4 project that I need to integrate Vue 3 with Vite. Mainly, I need to know the best practices, like folder structure, Vite auto build on file save (and how to start with the debugging session). I've worked on an existing Vue 2 with MVC 4 project using webpack. Just curious about differences, and gotchas I might see.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the documentation on the vite official website,[enter link description here](https://vitejs.dev/guide/backend-integration.html) it's worked for me, but the difference is my backend use express.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).